# Call to a member function updat_data() on null

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have got this problem, I tried many ways but I couldnt reach a soulution.
this is my **main.php code** for updation it edits the data but doesnot insert it to update . null error is in `updat_data()` function. Please help. I am confused.

```
function get_data($id){

    $this->index();



    $data['ed']= $this->main_model->get_data($id);
    $this->load->view('edit',$data);
    }




    public function update_data()
    {

        $id = $this->input->post('id');

        $data= array('first_name' =>$this->input->post('first_name') , 'last_name' =>$this->input->post('last_name') );


        $this->main_model->updat_data($id,$data);
        $this->load->model("main_model");


    }
```

this is model.php code for update..

```
function get_data($id)
    {
        //$this->db->where("id", $id);
///     $this->db->update("user",$data);
        $this->db->where("id",$id);
        $query=$this->db->get("user");
        return $query->result();


    }

    function updat_data($id,$data)
    {

        $this->db->where('id',$id);
         $this->db->update('user',$data);

        //return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try to load the model before you use it in main.php

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Thanks I won't do it again in the future.